# Improve body tracking performance of VNDetectHumanBodyPoseRequest

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, vision, avkit

I am trying to improve the performance of drawing the skeleton with body tracking for `VNDetectHumanBodyPoseRequest` even when further than 5 metres away, and with a stable iPhone XS camera.

The tracking has low confidence for the lower right limbs of my body, noticeable lag and there is jitter. I am unable to replicate the showcased performance in this year's WWDC [demo video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10043).

Here is the relevant code, adapted from [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_human_body_poses_in_images):

```
class Predictor {
  func extractPoses(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) throws -> [VNRecognizedPointsObservation] {
    let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cmSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, orientation: .down)
    
    let request = VNDetectHumanBodyPoseRequest()
    
    do {
      // Perform the body pose-detection request.
      try requestHandler.perform([request])
    } catch {
      print("Unable to perform the request: \(error).\n")
    }
    
    return (request.results as? [VNRecognizedPointsObservation]) ?? [VNRecognizedPointsObservation]()
  }
}
```

I've captured the video data and am handling the sample buffers here:

```
class CameraViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

  func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    let observations = try? predictor.extractPoses(sampleBuffer)
    observations?.forEach { processObservation($0) }
  }

  func processObservation(_ observation: VNRecognizedPointsObservation) {
    
    // Retrieve all torso points.
    guard let recognizedPoints =
            try? observation.recognizedPoints(forGroupKey: .all) else {
      return
    }
    
    let storedPoints = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: recognizedPoints.compactMap { (key, point) -> (String, CGPoint)? in
      return (key.rawValue, point.location)
    })
    
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
      let mappedPoints = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: recognizedPoints.compactMap { (key, point) -> (String, CGPoint)? in
        guard point.confidence > 0.1 else { return nil }
        let norm = VNImagePointForNormalizedPoint(point.location,
                                                  Int(drawingView.bounds.width),
                                                  Int(drawingView.bounds.height))
        return (key.rawValue, norm)
      })
      
      let time = 1000 * observation.timeRange.start.seconds
      
      
      // Draw the points onscreen.
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.drawingView.draw(points: mappedPoints)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `drawingView.draw` function is for a custom `UIView` on top of the camera view, and draws the points using `CALayer` sublayers. The `AVCaptureSession` code is exactly the same as the sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_hand_poses_with_vision).

I tried using the `VNDetectHumanBodyPoseRequest(completionHandler:)` variant but this made no difference to the performance for me. I could try smoothing with a moving average filter though.. but there is still a problem with outlier predictions which are very inaccurate.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you were not able to solve it? Any updates?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar problem and I'm very interested on this. Did you find a solution that you could share? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug on iOS 14 beta v1-v3 I think. After upgrading to v4 and later beta releases, tracking is much better. The API also became a bit clearer with fine-grained type names with the latest beta updates.

Note I didn’t get an official answer from Apple regarding this bug, but this problem will probably completely disappear in the official iOS 14 release.

Comment: I also implemented a Moving Average filter but that made things worse since it removes/smoothes out quick movements. Probably a Weighted Moving Average Filter would work better